# who first defined a tangent to a circle as a line meeting it only once?

Tags: geometry, math-history

From googling, it seems commonly believed that Euclid did this, but it seems nowhere in Euclid does he even state this property of a tangent line explicitly.  Rather Euclid gives 4 other equivalent properties,  that the line does not cross the circle, that it is perpendicular to the radius, that is a limit of secant lines, and that it makes an angle of zero with the circle, the first of which is his definition, the others being in Proposition III.16.  I am wondering where the "meets only once" definition got started.  I presume once it got going, and people stopped reading Euclid, (which seems to have occurred over 100 years ago), the currently popular definition took over.  Perhaps I should consult Legendre or Hadamard?  Thank you for any leads.

Well I have found this definition in Hadamard's lessons in plane geometry.  Any earlier references?

I have also found another equivalent characterization of a tangent by Euclid, Prop. (III.36-37):  A segment PX, from a point P outside a circle and meeting the circle at X, is tangent to the circle at X if and only if there exists another segment PB, meeting the circle first at A and then at B, such that (PA)(PB) = (PX)^2, [in terms either of equality squares of lengths of segments, or of equality of area of rectangles].

Comment: I think looking for Hadamard is a little too recent. Perhaps if not Euclid my first try would be to look at the beginning of the speaking of tangents, which brings you to the Newton/Leibniz era.

Comment: finding tangents is a old problem, one motivation for newton's calculus.  decartes studied the problem http://www.maths.tcd.ie/pub/HistMath/People/Descartes/RouseBall/RB_Descartes.html and probably people before him...

Answer (score 3):

Some googling points to Archimedes (use ctrl-F to find his name in this article)

http://math.ucsd.edu/~ashenk/Section2_8.pdf

Comment: Seems that crafty Archimedes had calculus up his sleeve all along. Damn shame we had to wait a quarter shy of two millenia for Newton et al to remake it.

Comment: Actually that article claims incorrectly that Euclid said this, and even cites Euclid for it.  Maybe he means it follows from Euclid's definition.

Comment: I see he cites page one in Heath's translation. I do n ot have access to that, but I wonder what it says there.  E.g. is he citing a remark of Heath, or is Heath making an interpretation, or a different translation?  Does anyone have volume 2 of that Dover book?

Comment: He also cites Appolonius for one of Euclid's other characterizations as a line such that no other line lies between the curve and it.  It makes me wonder if that author has read Euclid.