# Did tangent orginate from geometry, calculus, or trigonometry?

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, tangent-line

This is a very simple question but I wasn't able to find a question like it and I wasn't a math major.  Did tangent originate in trigonometry, geometry, or calculus?  I remember using tangent lines in geometry, trig, and calculus but I'm curious which came first.

http://www.mathopenref.com/tangentline.html

Comment: @suomynonA It seems like Alex is talking about tangent lines, not $\tan x$

Comment: @ovi Oops, thanks for the correction

Comment: The notion of a tangent line was geometrically known to Greeks, long before trigonometry or calculus evolved. See for example [who first defined a tangent to a circle as a line meeting it only once?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55065/who-first-defined-a-tangent-to-a-circle-as-a-line-meeting-it-only-once).

Comment: I didn't know about the relationship with the pyramid shadows and tan. That's interesting as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of a tangent line definitely doesn't originate with calculus, as this branch of mathematics was only discovered in the last few hundred years by Newton and Leibniz, while the idea of tangent lines is much older than that.

Trigonometry is an offshoot of geometry, and tangent lines are definitely present in geometry. So the tangent lines probably originate from : Geometry.

One of the simplest (read: earliest) applications of tangent lines is the fact that a line tangent to a circle is perpendicular to the radius.

Comment: Yay!  A fellow discoverist.

Comment: Only 10 reputation to 6300 - make me riiiich

Comment: It is derived from the latin word *tangere* - to touch.